# The '[]' operator is not defined for the 'Object' type. Try defining the '[]' operator

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I get the following error when I try to add data to my database in Flutter:

> The '[]' operator is not defined for the 'Object' type. Try defining
> the '[]' operator.

```
void initState() {
super.initState();

DatabaseReference postsRef= FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Posts");
postsRef.once().then((DatabaseEvent event) {
  if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
      var KEYS = event.snapshot.value!.keys;
      var DATA = event.snapshot.value;
      postsList.clear();
        for (var individualKey in KEYS) {
          Posts posts = Posts(
          DATA![individualKey]['image'],
          DATA[individualKey]['description'],
          DATA[individualKey]['date'],
          DATA[individualKey]['time'],
      );
      postsList.add(posts);
    }
    setState(() {
      print('Length: ${postsList.length}');
    });
  }
});  
}
```

Comment: Can you try this way?  >> DATA![individualKey]['description'],

Comment: yes ı try this way it's not working

Comment: Hmm :/ I dont know then. I see this just this error..Maybe something else trigger this error?